# How to process query parameters in form of a list of tuples?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, query-string

Given a list of tuples for parameter names and values e.g.:

```
[("foo", 10), ("bar", None), ("baz", "some_string")]
```

and some url string e.g.:

```
"/some/url/string"
```

my function should be able to create following output string (Note that None value tuples are not included in the query string):

```
"/some/url/string?foo=10&baz=some_string"
```

I tried using join but since the values are not all strings, I would have to convert them first. Maybe someone can help me with a short and clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> data = [("foo", 10), ("bar", None), ("baz", "some_string")]
>>> urlencode(data)
'foo=10&bar=None&baz=some_string'
>>> urlencode([x for x in data if x[1] is not None]) # no None's
'foo=10&baz=some_string'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the built-in [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) to encode the parameters for you.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> parameters = [("foo", 10), ("bar", None), ("baz", "some_string")]
>>> clean_parameters = [parameter for parameter in parameters if parameter[1] is not None]
>>> urllib.urlencode(clean_parameters)
'foo=10&baz=some_string'
```

Comment: `if parameter[1]` blocks values of `0`. Use `if parameter[1] is not None`

Comment: True, that does bite me when I type faster than I think. :)

Comment: @ChristianWitts It would be a good idea to update/correct your answer, not everyone will read all the comments.